# TTL cache for the Joomla custom-module

Tags: php, caching, joomla, joomla3.0

Please, help me...
I can not set the TTL cache for the Joomla module. This is -

```
$cache->setLifeTime(20);
```

- not working.

My code:

```
$cache = & JFactory::getCache('my_custom_mod', '');
$cacheKey = (string)$urls->serialize();

if (!($data = $cache->get($cacheKey))){
    foreach ($urls as $i => $url){
        $data[$i] = file_get_contents($url);
    }
    $cache->setLifeTime(20);
    $cache->store($data, $cacheKey);
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Could you clarify "not working"? Are you getting an error? was the code ever actually executed? Are you getting unexpected results? What results *were* you expecting?

Comment: The cache file is not updated after 20 seconds: $cache->setLifeTime(20);

Answer (score 1):

[solved](http://masterpro.ws/alternative-caching-joomla-module)

```
$cache = JFactory::getCache('mod_jexchange_rates_cbr', ''); // Any unique name
$cache->setCaching(true); // Force cache enable.
```

If caching is disabled in the Global Configuration, that would be why your data isn’t caching. If you need it to persist regardless of global cache setting.

```
$cache->setLifeTime(60); //Minutes
```